# Is it possible to create comments in public media using Instagram Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

As this week's Facebook major changes to Instagram API ([first on rate limiting](https://techcrunch.com/2018/04/02/instagram-api-limit/) then [removing almost all capabilities](https://techcrunch.com/2018/04/04/facebook-instagram-api-shut-down/)) forced the move to Instagram Graph API, does anyone know if is possible to post a comment from a business account to someone else's public media using Instagram Graph API?

I know there is [an endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media/comments#create) to create comments by sending a `POST` to `/{mediaId}/comments?message={messageText}`, but how can I get the Graph API Object ID for that media? The media ID on Instagram is completely different from Graph's Object ID.

As I can see [in the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media#metadata), in Graph API we can only retrieve the metadata of the media owned by our business user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use webhooks to retrieve IDs from objects that your business was mentioned. The following https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/mentions should also work but at the moment it doesn't seem so.

Then you'd use the mentions edge (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/mentions) to post the comment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @phwd. I know about the mentions webhook, but that will not work for me, as I need to post a comment on any public media from the business account, without any mention.

Comment: Based on the recent API restrictions as well as the current documentation, the only media you will be able to comment on via the API are media objects your business was mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

- One alternative to post a comment in a media is being the media owner.

`POST /{mediaId}/comments?message={messageText}&access_token={user_access_token}`

For example, for this query work the `user_access_token` needs to be the same user that created the media

- Another alternative to post a comment in a media is to respond a media in where you were mentioned, that could be achieved doing the following

`POST /{ig-user-id}/mentions?media_id={media_id}&message={message}&access_token={user_access_token}`

where the `user_access_token` need to be the same user mentioned in the media